# Template function implementation in a separate header file giving an error when testing

Tags: c++, templates, header-files, function-templates

This is for an assignment I have where we are to write a queue template class using a linked list. There is the main file `QueueT.h` which has the Node class for the linked list, the QueueT class definition and the QueueT method implementations. Then there is another file called `QFunctions.h` where we are to write the implementation of some template functions for the class. The problem is occurring when I try to test one of the template functions (in another file called `test.cpp`) and the compiler is giving an error saying one of the template functions was not declared in the scope.

QueueT.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <ostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::ostream;

// NodeT class definition
template <class T>
class NodeT{
public:

}

// QueueT class definition
template <class T>
class QueueT{
public:

    // other functions 

    QueueT<T> qconcatenate(QueueT<T> q1, QueueT<T> q2);

private:

}

// function implementations below here
```

QFunctions.h

```
#include "QueueT.h"
#include <stack>

// PRE: input and output queues must contain the same type of data
// PARAM: 
// POST: returns a QueueT object that contains the contents of the parameters
template <class T>
QueueT<T> QueueT<T>::qconcatenate(QueueT<T> q1, QueueT<T> q2) {
    QueueT<T> q3;
    NodeT<T>* temp = q1.front;

    while (temp != nullptr) {
        q3.insert(temp->data);
        temp = temp->next;
    }

    return q3;
}
```

test.cpp

```
#include "QFunctions.h"

int main(){
    cout << "SIMPLE TEST" << endl;

    QueueT<int> q1;
 
    q1.enqueue(64);
    q1.enqueue(123);
    q1.enqueue(7);
    q1.enqueue(1);
 
    q1.print();
    cout << "size of q1: " << q1.size() << endl;
    cout << endl;

    QueueT<int> q2(q1);

    q1.dequeue();
    q2.dequeue();
    q2.dequeue();
    q2.enqueue(67);
    q1.enqueue(23);
    
    QueueT<int> q3;
    q3 = qconcatenate<int>(q1,q2);

    q1.print();
    cout << "size of q1 (post copy): " << q1.size() << endl;
    cout << endl;

    q2.print();
    cout << "size of q2 (copy): " << q2.size() << endl;
    cout << endl;

    q3.print();
    cout << "size of q3 (op=): " << q3.size() << endl;
    cout << endl;
 
    cout << "END SIMPLE TEST" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

And so when I go to compile the code, it give me this error:

[g++ compiler error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5KRu.png)

Comment: Errors must be shown as a plain pre-formated text in the question.

Comment: Neither of the classes in `QueueT.h` have a terminating `;`.  `qconcatenate` is a member function so it requires an instance to call it. `q1.qconcatenate(q1,q2);` would work although it seems awkward. Perhaps you meant for it to be a free function? You might consider a [mcve] that is all in one block and can be copy/pasted to compile and test. This would help you too since once you have it all working in one place you can see if splitting it into multiple headers is the issue or not. In this case it just looks like misuse based on the design.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Ah, I think they are supposed to be implemented as free functions, I never knew that was a difference. They shouldn't require an instance to be called. Thank you!